# getting many error in angular 2 for deploying google cloud vision ocr

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, google-cloud-platform

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ManualService {

  constructor() {
    // Imports the Google Cloud client library.

    const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
 // Instantiates a client. If you don't specify credentials when constructing
 // the client, the client library will look for credentials in the
 // environment.
 const storage = Storage();

 // Makes an authenticated API request.
 storage
   .getBuckets()
   .then((results) => {
     const buckets = results[0];

     console.log('Buckets:');
     buckets.forEach((bucket) => {
       console.log(bucket.name);
     });
   })
   .catch((err) => {
     console.error('ERROR:', err);
   });
   }


}
```

I am Deploying Google cloud vision Ocr in My angular2 webapp.but i am getting many of the errors when i add this code in my webapp code.please help me to sort out this.

When I run this code ,it gives me this output:
[image: error]

Comment: I suggest you upgrade to version 5. Angular version 2 is over a year old and has a lot of deprecated APIs.

Comment: hello @LazarLjubenović it didnt work for me.i am trying to deploying google cloud vision ocr nodejs code in my angular2 using service.can you please help me to deply this.

Answer (score 1):

do this

> npm install

or

> sudo npm install